# Google Drive API show wrong storageQuota

Tags: google-drive-api

Just checked my client app today, and it seems the Google Drive API not working correctly. The `storageUsage` field and `usage` field displaying the incorrect value.
I tried the API from [the link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get?authuser=4&apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22storageQuota%22%7D) and it's also incorrect

The result of API call is from my client app and google API test page (link above):

```
{
    "storageQuota": {
       "limit": "16106127360",
       "usage": "980663126",
       "usageInDrive": "7992",
       "usageInDriveTrash": "0"
    }
}
```

But the correct value should be:
[image]

Is this really a bug or what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance for help.

**EDIT 1.**

Just to clarify, the problem here is Drive API returns incorrect value for `usage` field. As the example shown, it return 0.9 Gb as `usage` field but the correct value of `usage` field is 4.46 Gb

Comment: Your issue is what exactly?

Comment: @DaImTo Drive API return incorrect value for `usage` field

Comment: And what is incorrect about that value?

Comment: @DaImTo Drive API returns 0,9 GB as used storage, but the correct value is 4 GB

Comment: So you think the drive API is going to report you storage in gmail?

Comment: @DaImTo I want to get Used storage of my google account. (4,46 Gb). And I'm using Drive API to archive that, `usage` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `About:get` `storageQuota.usage` and `quotaBytesUsedAggregate` only correct if there is any changes made in Google Drive such as add, update, delete files. I guess it triggers the update function to update latest data. Otherwise, it will never work.

Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [About.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) method you will notice that it clearly states

[image]

Now you may also notice the term `system capabilities`, this term has never been clarified by the drive team. I suspect it has something to do with app data stored on your drive account. In my exprecint this method only returns drive storage space.

I am not aware of any method that will return a users storage on their full google account.  That being said I pinged a devrel at Google to see if he can define exactly what `system capabilities` means.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for your help. I'm afraid that the method `get` is not about the user's drive storage space because it was correct before. that means the used storage have been 0.9 Gb in my example.<br> I suspect there is a delay in updating user storage for this method.

Answer (score 0):

`Drive v3`'s `about.get` field `storageQuota.usage` should be the aggregate of all the used quota. [As per documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about#storageQuota.usage):

> storageQuota.usage | long | The total usage across all services.

It should include Google Drive, Gmail, and Google Photos.

If this doesn't seem to properly work for you, there is another way of querying this data: `Drive v2`. It also has an `about.get` ([see reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about/get)) but, unlike in `v3`, it has a `quotaBytesByService` field that can help you debug this. Notice that `quotaBytesUsedAggregate` on `v2` should equal to the `storageQuota.usage` on `v3`.

### References

- [About: get (Drive v3 reference)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)
- [About: get (Drive v2 reference)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about/get)

Comment: The About:get storageQuota.usage and quotaBytesUsedAggregate only correct if there is any changes made in Google Drive such as add, update, delete files. Thank you for your help